# Calculation of BigDecimal

Tags: java, jasper-reports, arithmetic-expressions

I'm having a problem getting this calculation down. I can do addition, subtract, etc...
but what I'm trying to do is this ((a - b)/b) in Jasper reports.

Here's what I've tried so far

```
${Budget}.subtract($F{Actual})/$F{Budget}
```

but when I compile it. It says that I have an expression problem. I'm using Jasper Studio expression editor

Both $F{Budget} and $F{Actual} are text fields and Class java.math.BigDecimal

Here's the stace trace

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression : 
Source text : $F{Budgeted}.subtract($F{Actual}.divide($F{Budgeted}))

at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportControler.fillReport(ReportControler.java:475)

at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportControler.access$18(ReportControler.java:450)

at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportControler$4.run(ReportControler.java:337)

at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)

    Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression : 
Source text : $F{Budgeted}.subtract($F{Actual}.divide($F{Budgeted}))

at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluateEstimated(JREvaluator.java:308)

at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.evaluateEstimated(JRCalculator.java:582)

at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.estimateVariables(JRCalculator.java:181)

at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:1261)

at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:1235)

at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.next(JRBaseFiller.java:1588)

at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:149)

at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:939)

at         net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseFillHandle$ReportFiller.run(BaseFillHandle.java:120)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Caused by: java.lang.ArithmeticException: Division by zero

at java.math.BigDecimal.divide(Unknown Source)

at ProjectSummary_1398114778002_614232.evaluateEstimated(ProjectSummary_1398114778002_614232:405)

at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluateEstimated(JREvaluator.java:295)

... 9 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`${Budget}.subtract($F{Actual})` will return a `BigDecimal` reference, so you cannot use division symbol `/` because this is only supported for primitives (and their class wrappers when unboxed). So, you should use [`BigDecimal#divide`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide-java.math.BigDecimal-) instead.

```
${Budget}.subtract($F{Actual}).divide($F{Budget})
```

---

From your question edit:

> Caused by: java.lang.ArithmeticException: Division by zero

Your `$F{Budget}` variable should not have a zero value. You could use a ternary operator to solve this problem:

```
${Budget}.subtract($F{Actual}).divide( ($F{Budget}.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0 ? BigDecimal.ONE : $F{Budget}) )
```

---

From a new comment:

> I need if $F{Budget} is zero that calculation field gets assigned zero and a number other wise.

Just modify the usage of ternary operator:

```
($F{Budget} == null || $F{Budget}.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0)) ? BigDecimal.ZERO : $F{Budget}.subtract($F{Actual}).divide($F{Budget})
```

Comment: I tried it like that and it gives me error evaluating expression

Comment: This is the correct way to do it, but maybe you have an additional error.  Can you give the exact text of your error please, after you apply this fix?

Comment: @EricEvans I'm not sure if you really have both `${Budget}` and `$F{Budget}`, review your code.

Comment: @EricEvans please do not edit the answer, instead post a comment with the relevant info.

Comment: Sorry for the previouse acceptance my problem is still here with that bit of code. I need if $F{Budget} is zero that calculation field gets assigned zero and a number other wise.

Comment: @EricEvans seriously, you can come with the appropriate answer based on this proposed solution. Anyway, updated the answer based on your *new* requirement...

Comment: Luiggi sorry man it's just not returning what I'm needing. I need for it to return 0 and it's returning null. I'll give you the rating, I just need to get pass this

Comment: @EricEvans if this gives you `null` means that `$F{Budget}` should be `null`. Added a `null` check in the expression. Let me know if there's any other problem

Comment: Thanks Luiggi sorry for the problems Eclipse was messing up, so I deleted the variable and create another one. It works Thanks again.

Comment: When i do this, it returns 2 errors **`net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file:
The method compareTo(Integer) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (BigDecimal) and  The method subtract(Integer) is undefined for the type Integer`

Comment: @gigz the stacktrace is telling you the cause of the error. Seems like one of your variables is of type `Integer` and you're treating it as `BigDecimal`, thus it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing a pair of ()?

Which will create ambiguity of your expression if no association is specified. (Compiler/Parser)

Answer (score 0):

Look at your stack trace.  It has this line.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArithmeticException: Division by zero
```

So `$F{Budget}` is zero, and it's only right that you should be unable to divide by it.